# c# groupBox how to delete this lines?

Tags: c#, groupbox

how to delete this white lines in a `GroupBox`?

[image]

Comment: Why is there a group box in the first place? If you need an invisible container, you can use a `Panel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the .BorderStyle Property to something that looks better, i.e. none.

But rather not use a group control at all, or any other grouping control that may have some visible lines.

Panels are much more suitable for this (as per suggestions above).